# How to resolve Runtime error no transaction is active?

Tags: sql-server, vba, transactions, distributed-transactions

I am dealing with a legacy program written in Visual Basic the source code of which is unfortunately unavailable to me. The set up I have is the following.

There is a server, lets call it **S**, and two client computers, **A** and **B**.
The application is a basic CRUD application, lets you view, add, update and delete fields from the server **S**.

The program is installed on both **A** and **B** and works fine on **A**, 
however on computer **B** while doing some operation such as requesting a certain table from server **S** I get

> Run time error - no transaction is active

**EDIT**
I have tried turning off, uninstalling and installing MSDTC, made sure that DCOMCNFG TCP/IP is selected.
Has anyone encountered this problem?

Comment: `tried turning off, uninstalling and installing MSDTC` - but have you [restarted the entire server](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/SECURITY/en-US/798bcecc-e355-4ac0-b047-98a1a3dbeefa/no-transaction-is-active-error-with-linked-servers-in-sql-2008-r2?forum=sqlkjappmsmgmt#9e25c395-81b7-4f01-bca9-a40bbc9975ee)?

Comment: Yes I have. Unfortunately, didn’t work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the program works on one computer but not on the other, and NetBios is active, MSDTC is active too, then it's an issue with the software not winsock or the server. Try running the program in compatibility mode of the last known windows that it is know to work on. (Usually it is win xp sp3).